# How to modify latex package documentation

Tags: packages, documentation

Let's say I want to modify the documentation of certain package. I download the `.dtx` and `.ins` files and I see that the documentation is in the `.dtx` file but it's commented. If I compile the `.ins` file I get the `.sty` file. Why is the documentation commented and how do I get the `.pdf`?

Comment: compile the .dtx file directly to get the PDF of the manual.

Comment: Ok that worked.

Comment: The format of a dtx is interpreted differently by the compiler so that single `%` are part of the document, double `%%` remain comments.  Stuff in the `macrocode` environment is extracted by the `ins` compilations, etc.  Very complicated, but it all works.  It uses the `ltxdoc` documentclass.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes -- you might make that an answer.  i don't remember seeing this question elsewhere, at least not phrased in this way.  (but you should probably check for duplicates also.  unfortunately, i haven't time right now.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not an expert on dtx files, even though I've written a few.  If I recall, I took an existing .dtx file and adapted it for my use.  Along those lines, I provide a very stripped down `sample.dtx` file below (and the associated `sample.ins`).  With it, I show both the `sample.sty` and `sample.pdf` files that are extracted from it.

What are some of the salient points to take in:

A. the line `\generate{\file{sample.sty}{\from{sample.dtx}{package}}}` in the ins file says to look in the dtx file for the lines identified as the "package".  These are identified in two ways:

1. Lines beginning with `<package>` identify the package and end up in the sty file.
2. `%<*package>` and `%</package>` delimiters in the dtx file identify all intervening lines as the "package", for extracting `sample.sty`.  Within that range, anything starting with a single `%` is not extracted into the sty file, but anything beginning with a `%%` *is* extracted into the sty file as a comment.

B. dtx files use the `ltxdoc` document class.  It follows different rules.  I don't know them all, but here are a few takeaways:

1. the `%<*driver>` and `%</driver>` delimiters provide code definitions in the standard LaTeX way that may be needed to compile the dtx documentation.
2. The `\iffalse` and `\fi` delimiters around the `<package>` and `<driver>` regions are necessary.  If omitted, the compilation fails.
3. The `\CheckSum{}` macro is optional and is used to guarantee file integrity after a file transmission. If the argument is incorrect, it generates an error during compilation, telling you what checksum it expected and what checksum you specified.  As the package developer, you edit the parameter value to be the same that the compiler told you, and then the error disappears.  If the file gets corrupted during transmission, an error will reappear (with modern transmission error corrections, this is something of a quaint throwback).
4. After the `%</driver>` and `% \fi` lines, the dtx document compilation follows the `ltxdoc` rules, in which a leading `%` is stripped from each line for creating the document.
5. The environment `%    \begin{macrocode}...%   \end{macrocode}` (in which the four blank characters between the `%` and `\begin` are essential) delimits code that will be displayed as verbatim code.  It will be numbered in this case, because `\CodelineNumbered` was an option in the `<driver>` code.
6. The environment `\begin{macro}{`*macro-name*`}...\end{macro}` is used to enclose both an associated `macrocode` environment defining *macro-name* as well as the description of that macro.
7. According to the LaTeX Companion, `\StopEventually{}` separates the source file into a "user documentation" and "implementation" part.
8. As to `\Finale`, this runs anything delayed from the earlier `\StopEventually`, which doesn't really do anything in this particular example.

With the advent of .ZIP files, I think the need for dtx formats may be lessened.  But in the days before .ZIP, putting both code and documentation into a single file was a big plus, both for version control, and for data transmission.

Here is the `sample.dtx` file that is small enough in size that you can hopefully follow its parts and pieces easily.  As to how to modify documentation, you can easily see in this dtx MWE where different parts of the documentation originate.  Therefore, I hope that it might help you in understanding what parts of a dtx are modified to reflect changes in the documentation.

```
% \CheckSum{9}
% \iffalse
%%
%% sample.sty
%% Comments and license info
%%
%<package>\ProvidesPackage{sample}
%<package>[2015/02/16 v1.00
%<package> Tools for absolutely nothing]
%<package>\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
%<*driver>
% V1.00-Initial release (version control could go here)
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{sample}
\DisableCrossrefs
\CodelineNumbered
% DEFINE SOME COMMANDS THAT ARE EASIER HERE THAN IN DocInput ENVIRONMENT
\let\iq\itshape%     SHORTHAND FOR ITALIC  FONT
\let\uq\upshape%     SHORTHAND FOR UPSHAPE FONT
\newcommand\sample{\textsf{sample}}
\GetFileInfo{sample.sty}
\begin{document}
   \title{The \textsf{sample} Package\\
         \rule{0em}{0.7em}\small\fileinfo}
   \author{A. Nonymous\\
           nulname@gmail.com}
   \date{\filedate\\
         \fileversion}
   \maketitle
   \DocInput{sample.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
% \parskip 1ex
% \begin{abstract}
% This is the package abstract
% \end{abstract}
%
% \tableofcontents
%
%\noindent\hrulefill
%
% \section {Introduction}
%
% blah-blah
%
% \subsection{Commands}
%
% This \sample{} package provides the macros named:
% 
% \noindent
% |\sampleA[|\iq integer\uq|]{|\iq text\uq|}|\\
% |\sampleB[|\iq integer\uq|]{|\iq text\uq|}|
%
% Here is a description of their use.
% 
% \DescribeMacro{\sampleA}
% The routine |\sampleA| is useful for nothing.
%
% \DescribeMacro{\SampleB}
% Likewise, the macro |\sampleB| is also pretty much useless.
%
% \section{Sample Usage}
%
% The code |\sampleA[3]{test}\sampleB[5]{I win.}| will result in
%
% \sampleA[3]{test}\sampleB[5]{I win.}
%
% This package provides little utility. The only thing left
% is the code listing itself.
%% \CharacterTable
%%  {Upper-case    \A\B\C\D\E\F\G\H\I\J\K\L\M\N\O\P\Q\R\S\T\U\V\W\X\Y\Z
%%   Lower-case    \a\b\c\d\e\f\g\h\i\j\k\l\m\n\o\p\q\r\s\t\u\v\w\x\y\z
%%   Digits        \0\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9
%%   Exclamation   \!     Double quote  \"     Hash (number) \#
%%   Dollar        \$     Percent       \%     Ampersand     \&
%%   Acute accent  \'     Left paren    \(     Right paren   \)
%%   Asterisk      \*     Plus          \+     Comma         \,
%%   Minus         \-     Point         \.     Solidus       \/
%%   Colon         \:     Semicolon     \;     Less than     \<
%%   Equals        \=     Greater than  \>     Question mark \?
%%   Commercial at \@     Left bracket  \[     Backslash     \\
%%   Right bracket \]     Circumflex    \^     Underscore    \_
%%   Grave accent  \`     Left brace    \{     Vertical bar  \|
%%   Right brace   \}     Tilde         \~}
% \StopEventually{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \begin{macro}{sample.sty}
% \section{Code Listing}
% I'll try to lay out herein
% the workings of the \sample style package.  
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*package>
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
%
% \begin{macro}{mysample}
% We start by defining and initializing the counter that is used.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcounter{mysample}
\setcounter{mysample}{0}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
%
% \begin{macro}{\sampleA}
% The routine |\sampleA| will do absolutely nothing,
% except for setting |mycounter| to the value of |#1|.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand\sampleA[2][0]{%
  \setcounter{mysample}{#1}%
}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
% \begin{macro}{\sampleB}
% The routine |\sampleB| will output |\themysample|
% surrounded by brackets.  It
% will then store |#1| as the counter |mysample|.
% Finally, it outputs |#2| followed by ``NOT!''.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand\sampleB[2][0]{%
  [\themysample]
  \setcounter{mysample}{#1}%
  #2 NOT!
}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
%
% We are done now.
%    \begin{macrocode}
%</package>
%    \end{macrocode}
%
% \Finale
\endinput
%
%End of file `sample.dtx'.
```

Here is the `sample.ins` file, used to extract the .sty file from the dtx file:

```
% LaTeX this .ins file in order to generate the .sty file from the .dtx file
\input docstrip
\askforoverwritefalse
\generate{\file{sample.sty}{\from{sample.dtx}{package}}
         }
\endbatchfile
```

If I compile the `sample.ins` file, the `sample.sty` file below is extracted:

```
%%
%% This is file `sample.sty',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% sample.dtx  (with options: `package')
%% 
%% IMPORTANT NOTICE:
%% 
%% For the copyright see the source file.
%% 
%% Any modified versions of this file must be renamed
%% with new filenames distinct from sample.sty.
%% 
%% For distribution of the original source see the terms
%% for copying and modification in the file sample.dtx.
%% 
%% This generated file may be distributed as long as the
%% original source files, as listed above, are part of the
%% same distribution. (The sources need not necessarily be
%% in the same archive or directory.)
%%
%% sample.sty
%% Comments and license info
%%
\ProvidesPackage{sample}
[2015/02/16 v1.00
 Tools for absolutely nothing]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
%% \CharacterTable
%%  {Upper-case    \A\B\C\D\E\F\G\H\I\J\K\L\M\N\O\P\Q\R\S\T\U\V\W\X\Y\Z
%%   Lower-case    \a\b\c\d\e\f\g\h\i\j\k\l\m\n\o\p\q\r\s\t\u\v\w\x\y\z
%%   Digits        \0\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9
%%   Exclamation   \!     Double quote  \"     Hash (number) \#
%%   Dollar        \$     Percent       \%     Ampersand     \&
%%   Acute accent  \'     Left paren    \(     Right paren   \)
%%   Asterisk      \*     Plus          \+     Comma         \,
%%   Minus         \-     Point         \.     Solidus       \/
%%   Colon         \:     Semicolon     \;     Less than     \<
%%   Equals        \=     Greater than  \>     Question mark \?
%%   Commercial at \@     Left bracket  \[     Backslash     \\
%%   Right bracket \]     Circumflex    \^     Underscore    \_
%%   Grave accent  \`     Left brace    \{     Vertical bar  \|
%%   Right brace   \}     Tilde         \~}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcounter{mysample}
\setcounter{mysample}{0}
\newcommand\sampleA[2][0]{%
  \setcounter{mysample}{#1}%
}
\newcommand\sampleB[2][0]{%
  [\themysample]
  \setcounter{mysample}{#1}%
  #2 NOT!
}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `sample.sty'.
```

On the other hand, if I compile `sample.dtx`, I get the following PDF:

[image]

[image]