# What is the most effective and efficient way to document a package?

Tags: package-writing, documentation

I'm sure this must be a duplicate but the questions I've found don't quite address the question I have.

Related questions include:

- [How to modify package documentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228133/how-to-modify-latex-package-documentation)
- [How to document style files for the use of author and collaborators](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13028/how-do-i-document-my-style-files)
- [Automatic linking of keywords in TikZ documentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33946/automatic-linking-aka-code-highlight-in-till-tantaus-codeexample)

I know that the `.dtx`/`.ins` formula is the traditional method, but I do not want to use a method which requires me to re-extract the `.sty` file, for example, in order to test it every time I make a change. I know I can automate this using `make` or whatever but the time and faff would drive me nuts.

[I've also seen people suggest that it may not be the best option any more. For example, people point out that the existence of compressed archives makes the inclusion of documentation in the same file as the code less of an advantage, or say that well-commented code with separate user documentation is a better option than an integrated approach.]

So my question is how best to document the code of a package *qua* code if ***not*** using the `.dtx`/`.ins` approach. Note that I know almost nothing about documenting or even typesetting code. I have typeset a very, very little code just using a `verbatim` environment or whatever. Once.

Should the code just be documented in the source file via comments? Or should it be typeset somehow? Or...?

EDITED in light of David Carlisle's comments to exclude the `.dtx`/`.ins` option.

Comment: Do you mean the inline/in-package documentation?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Well, I assume that user documentation should not be inline. So partly I'm interested in how to produce *that*. But I'm also asking *whether* code should be commented inline, separately documented or documented in the user documentation. Basically, I have no idea how best to document a package. I have a method for font packages but those seem different - the code is much the same from package to package, and the differences are scattered in a bunch of different files so nothing but inline seems to make much sense there.

Comment: probably I'd say same as I said in this almost dup question  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226869/what-to-put-into-the-dtx-file/226873#226873

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How do you maintain code if it is in a `.dtx`? That is, how does it stay in sync with a `.sty`, for example? I've never really understood how it works. I found a question about using `sty2dtx` but that doesn't explain what you do if you later change the `.sty` file, presumably having filled out details in the `.dtx` file in the meantime.

Comment: the dtx is the _source_, the .sty is extracted from that.

Comment: @cfr see the readme of a new package that went to ctan today: https://github.com/davidcarlisle/dpctex/tree/master/elocalloc the sty isn't on ctan at all, you get the dtx and extract the package from it (essentially just removing comments in this case)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I know how to extract a `.sty` from a `.dtx` but if you make all changes to the `.dtx`, then you have to re-extract the `.sty` every time to test a change?

Comment: @cfr yes or more typically type `make` or `l3build` or something

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I guess I'll rule out the `.dtx` method, then ;). Would definitely drive me nuts.

Comment: @cfr in the usual case you can simply use the dtx file as the .sty (ie call it .sty) that of course was the original idea, that it's just a package with comments.  the stripping of comments was just for speed.

Comment: With the advent of ZIP archives, I'm somewhat of the opinion that the dtx approach is becoming archaic.  I have a few packages that use the dtx approach, but more recently, I just put the documentation in a tex file, separate from the sty file.  It all gets bundled in a zip archive and shipped off to CTAN.

Comment: The answer is probably: it depends. I'm not sure that my method is the “most” efficient way: I write code and manual separately using a custom class for the manual.

Comment: Might be interesting: LJR uses separate sty and TeX file in [`functional` package](https://github.com/lvjr/functional), then use some `\dochighinput` command to typeset the source code (with code highlighting I guess) and extract documentation etc..

Answer (score 5):

Don't rule out the `.dtx` method just yet `:)` With a nice makefile crafted for the occasion, your `.sty` is only a few keystrokes (and a few seconds) away. I use such a makefile for all of my LaTeX packages; see an example [here](https://github.com/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier/blob/master/makefile).

I favour the `.dtx` approach because it gives you colocation of documentation and code. I can't remember where I read/heard it, but comments can be thought of as code that never gets tested. Code that is never tested tends to become incorrect, over time. Keeping the documentation and the code it's meant to describe close together minimises the risk that the former deviates from the latter.

(One of these days, I swear I'll read my copy of Don Knuth's *Literate Programming* to make all this clearer in my mind.)